# Compare the rate of convergence of Jacobiand Gauss-Seidel method for the matrices

Tags: numerical-methods

Compare the rate of convergence of Jacobi and Gauss-Seidel method for the matrices

$$
A=\left(\begin{array}{rrr}
1 & 2 & -2 \\
1 & 1 & 1 \\
2 & 2 & 1
\end{array}\right), \quad B=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} & 1 & \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} & 1
\end{array}\right) .
$$

My solutions is as follows:

Matrix A

Jacobi

$$
\begin{gathered}
x^{k+1}=G x^{k}+b \\
G=-D^{-1}(A-D) \\
G=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & -2 & 2 \\
-1 & 0 & -1 \\
-2 & -2 & 0
\end{array}\right)
\end{gathered}
$$

$$
|G-\lambda E|=\left|\begin{array}{ccc}
-\lambda & -2 & 2 \\
-1 & -\lambda & -1 \\
-2 & -2 & -\lambda
\end{array}\right|=-\lambda^{3} \rightarrow r(G)=0
$$

Method is convergenced.

Seidel-Gauss

$$
\begin{gathered}
x^{k+1}=G x^{k}+b \\
G=-(D+L)^{-1} U \\
\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & -2 & 2 \\
0 & 2 & -3 \\
0 & 0 & 2
\end{array}\right) \rightarrow r(G)=2 \rightarrow \text { so method isn'tconvergenced. }
\end{gathered}
$$

Matrix B

Jacobi

Method is convergenced.

Seidel-Gauss

$$
x^{k+1}=G x^{k}+b
$$

$$
\begin{aligned}
& G=-(D+L)^{-1} U
\end{aligned}
$$

$G=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}0 & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \\ 0 & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \\ 0 & \frac{1}{9}(3-\sqrt{3}) & \frac{1}{9}(6-\sqrt{3})\end{array}\right) \rightarrow r(G)=0.45<1 \rightarrow$ so method istconvergenced.

$$
\begin{aligned}
& x^{k+1}=G x^{k}+b \\
& G=-D^{-1}(A-D) \\
& G=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}0 & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \\-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} & 0 & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \\-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} & 0\end{array}\right) \\
& \lambda E|=| \begin{array}{ccc}-\lambda & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \\-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} & -\lambda & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \\-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} & -\lambda\end{array} \mid
\end{aligned}
$$

Just want to check if this is correct.

Comment: You are not actually comparing the asymptotic rate of convergence. You are comparing the spectral radii which control upper bounds on the error which is something different.