# simple way to find convergence rate of Jacobi method

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods

Can someone please explain me how to find convergence rate here?

I’ve found somewhere that the rate of Jacobi convergence is equal to the rate of convergence of a geometric progression with a denominator q = ∥G2∥. Second norm of matrix G here is equal to √18. Is it correct and how to use it then?

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}1&2&-2\\1&1&1\\2&2&1\end{bmatrix}$$

$$G=D^{-1}(-L-U)=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}\cdot \begin{bmatrix}0&-2&2\\-1&0&-1\\-2&-2&0\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0&-2&2\\-1&0&-1\\-2&-2&0\end{bmatrix}$$

Eigenvalue $\lambda_{1}=0$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4478572/307944) explores the exact same matrix

Comment: This is more like the fastest rate of divergence. The matrix is not diagonally dominant.

Comment: Okay, even if it's divergence, is there any simple way to measure its rate?